# sqoop import from SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqoop

I am trying to connect SQL server through SQOOP but getting the below error:

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;username=kashif;password=sqoop;database=Northwind' --table Department -m 1;
13/09/26 04:41:22 INFO SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory: Using Microsoft's SQL Server - Hadoop Connector
13/09/26 04:41:22 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
13/09/26 04:41:22 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
13/09/26 04:41:37 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

I have downloaded the sqoop sql connector and placed it in /usr/lib/sqoop/lib folder also.

I have also checked that port 1433 is enabled for TCP connection.

Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

try this , replace the necessary ip userid pwd and db etc.,

sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://123.23.231.2;database=mydb" --username sa --password sa --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --table "mytable' --targer-dir "/tmp/mytable'